# Keil ARMCC Warning Macro

Tags: c, macros, compiler-warnings, pragma, keil

I want to write an all inclusive compiler warning message macro. How can you define such a macro to write out a warning given a certain compiler.

The standard for writing warnings is `#pragma message "warning"` which you can define in a macro using _Pragma, but when it comes to something like Keil you have to use `#warning` and a macro cannot be defined using `_Pragma` seeing as `#pragma` will precede the macro argument and Keil does not recognise `#prama warning`.

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#define COMP_MSG(msg)\
PRAGMA(message msg)
#elif defined(__ARMCC_VERSION)
// need code here
#endif

COMP_MSG("WARNING")
```

Comment: Well, then Keil cannot do that.

Comment: The whole point of using `#pragma` is to write _non-standard_, _non-portable_ things specific to one particular compiler.

Comment: `#pragma message` is not standard. It may be fairly common, but it isn’t formally standardized.

Comment: Are you sure `#warning` (parallel to `#error`, which is standardized) isn't more common than `#pragma message`?